# IOS/Storyboard/Autolayout. Center horizontal group of elements

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

Using autolayout in Storyboard, is there a straightforward way to center a group of elements without making them part of a subview?

For example if I have one label 50 and a second element Points, is there a way to hold them together as one and then center it.

Right now, I am able to hold the space between them constant (as it needs to be) and horizontally align but I can't get the two of them together centered.  My approach has been to set a leading space before the first element and a trailing space after the second element, but something is throwing it off.  I know I could combine them into one label and center it, but I'm looking for a solution that I can reuse every time I have one of these all too common situations.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Image:

[image]
Storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is very common and very simple to solve: just get rid of the `leading` and `trailing` constraints and instead add `horizontalCenter` to the first *label* regarding the view. After that all you gotta do is adding `horizontalCenter` to the second one regarding the first and you're set! Now both of them are linked together and well centered.

If you need more help with this, just share your repo and I'll fork it.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question specified that you don't want to make the two labels part of a subview, but I'm not aware of a good way to do that and thought I would at least mention that the standard / recommended way to handle this situation would be to add "3K" and "Points" to a horizontal stack view, and then horizontally center the stack view and vertically constrain it to "Explorer" above.

This would ultimately require the same or less constraints as what you have now because you wouldn't need to create constraints for the labels inside the stack view.

See Apple references here:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/?time=134

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html

Comment: Agree with you for IOS 9.0 and above.  Still supporting 8.0 however.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me.  This answer worked perfectly.